# Jpql fetch to fetch data from already existing database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have two tables in that one-to-many relationship exist i am not getting how to establish one to many relation between two table and how to write join fetch query

**Department Table**
dept_id --primary key
name VARCHAR(45),
department

**Employee Table**
 emp_id --primary key
 dep_id ---foreign key refrencing Department table pk
 name 
 phone_Number 
 email

I dried doing OneToMany Relation Like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="dept_id")
private Long id;

private String name;

@Column(name = "department_code")
private String departmentCode;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Employee> employees;

//getter setter




 @Entity
 @Table(name="employee")
 public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="emp_id")
private Long id;

private String name;

@Column(name = "dep_id")
private Long dpId;

@Column(name = "phone_Number")
private String phoneNumber;

private String email;
```

//getter setter

```
@Query(value = "select d from dept_uni d join fetch emp_uni e on d.id = e.dep_id where dept_id = :id")
Department findDepartmentById(@Param(value = "id") Long id);
```

How can I do Mapping and what should be the query with join fetch

Comment: I recommend that you first read a book. This one is really good: https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781430249276 there is also code that comes with the book: https://github.com/Apress/pro-jpa-2

Answer (score 1):

The way you have added the foreign key is not correct in the entity Employee.

Instead of

```
@Column(name = "dep_id")
private Long dpId;
```

You should have something like

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "dep_id")
private Department department;
```

Now you can access the department via the entity employee itself.

```
Employee emp = employeeRepo.findOne(1);
emp.getDepartment().getName();
```

Note: JPQL works with entities only. So it does not know your table `dept_uni` from the query you are trying to write. Instead you should have used your entity `Department`;

`select * from Department..`